# Use column values to build up query

Tags: postgresql

I have a table **log** containing columns **schema_name** & **table_name** & **object_id** & **data** and the table can contain records with different table_names and schema_names:

```
| schema_name   | table_name  | object_id   | data        |
| ------------- |-------------|-------------|-------------|
| bio           | sample      |5            |jsonb        |
| bio           | location    |8            |jsonb        |
| ...           | ...         |...          |jsonb        |
```

I want to execute a query as followed:

```
select schema_name, 
       table_name, 
       object_id, 
       (select some_column from schema_name.table_name where id = object_id) 
from log
```

PS: id is a column that exists in every table (sample, location, ...)

Is their a way in postgreSQL to use the values in columns to build up a query (so that schema_name and table_name is filled in based on the values of the columns)?

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? what object or item are you looking for in the database?

Comment: @Tito I want to add an extra column 'user' to the log table containing the id of the user who created the log. The user_id is present in all the tables (under column creation_user_id). So I need to extract the user id's from those tables to insert in the new log column. I would like to automate this process as I already have the table_name and schema_name.

Comment: are the columns you want to pull out coming from the data field(jsonb)?

Comment: Basically you need to use dynamic sql via an EXECUTE statement in order to construct a query with user-specified (or read from table... same thing) relations.